# How to use using GMail API

Tags: android, asp.net, gmail-api

I need help on how to use gmail api to authenticate user on my portal and application. I referred the documentation but I am not able to know how is it implemented. I already enable my gmail api and generated the credentials I am stuck at what to do next and how to use it in my asp project.

Comment: You're going to have to elaborate on what you're trying to achieve and where you're stuck.

Comment: I think you want firebase OAuth

Comment: @Malvin9000 I am looking for mechanism which can use google accounts to authenticate users on my portal and application.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need and Gmail API to authenticate user... you need firebase to manage the authentication.

[Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/?hl=es-419)

You can use:
Google
Facebook
Twitter
Github
Email.

Is the best option.

Comment: But its an client side authentication, It doesn't have server side authentication is it secure?

Comment: Is Gmail aut, Twitter aut, each platform... and is enough secure, you are using the same tools use google, and others companies.

Comment: How Can I use it with asp.net application?